# Is it possible to define a function pointer to a constructor?

Tags: c++, linux, design-patterns, unix, shared-libraries

I'm using shared library with explicit linking (loading shared lib with `dlopen`) in order to implement plugin pattern in C++.

Is it possible to define a function pointer to a constructor of a class defined in the shared library or I would have to define factory method, within shared lib, that would instantiate (and initialize) object of a class from shared lib? Of course in my main app, then, I would define a function pointer to a factory method, and that method would return an instance of the class I need.

Cheers

Comment: On Windows, you can use __declspec(dllexport/dllimport) to export and import constructors (and indeed whole classes). Would be worth checking the compiler documentation for your compiler to see if it offers anything similar.

Comment: On linux, everything is exported by default and you can just link to anything you want. But he is using explicit linking (think LoadLibrary/GetProcAddress in WinAPI) and honestly I have no idea how to handle constructors in such cases. It's a good question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer to the question is no, you can not define a member or function pointer to the constructor.

For dlopen, you need to provide a function with c linkage and load it dynamically, which you can use to create the objects, and you also need another function to delete objects.

More about it [here](http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-mini/C++-dlopen.html)

Comment: A really good article! What I liked the most is that it recommends to use base interfaces with pure virtual functions. Clearly it is the best way to implement plugins.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to be aware of the name mangling problems when fetching pointers with dlsym(). It's not a good idea to rely on some specific mangling method, they're all too diverse. So the only reasonable thing to do is to expose your plugin interface as extern "C" { ... }, with factory function wrappers over constructors.